# Why ruby sort array of strings differently than sql order (postgres)?

Tags: sql, ruby, postgresql

When the code would tell better than words:

```
[4] pry> Models::Company.order(:name).select_map(:name)
=> ["Dekker, Jacobs and Bosch", "Koster en Zonen", "Peters-Koster", "Peters, Vries and Smits", "Wal, Linden and Jacobs"]
[5] pry> Models::Company.order(:name).select_map(:name).sort
=> ["Dekker, Jacobs and Bosch", "Koster en Zonen", "Peters, Vries and Smits", "Peters-Koster", "Wal, Linden and Jacobs"]
```

Because of this my spec randomly failing. I can normalize arrays before comparing them, like this:

```
result_names.map { |s| s.gsub(/,|-/, '') }
```

I tried to sort the same array in JavaScript, and got the same result as Ruby gave me. I am wondering now, is there some sort of standard for sorting strings, or is it the detail of implementation?

Comment: Is the dash in "Peters-Koster" ascii 45 or long dash?

Comment: Something to do with [encoding or collation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/locale.html) configuration of your Postgres server, perhaps?

Comment: @DavidC Unfortunately, the environment has changed and I can't retrieve the same results to answer precisely. But I've tried to insert into db the same data that I've posted here, and I've got the same order that time. So I suppose this is because of [unicode dashes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dash)? It seems that Ruby normalizes such strings then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sort behaviour for strings in ruby based on ASCII codes.

Sort behaviour for text in pg depends on the current collation of your locale. From PostgreSQL wiki - [Why do my strings sort incorrectly?](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/FAQ#Why_do_my_strings_sort_incorrectly.3F):

> It is not in ASCII/byte order. No, it's not, it's not supposed to be.
>   ASCII is an encoding, not a sort order. If you want this, you can use
>   the C locale, but then you use the ability to non-ASCII characters.

So in plain SQL to sort by ASCII value, rather than a properly localized sort following your local language rules, you can use the [COLLATE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/collation.html) clause in query

```
order by name COLLATE "C" ASC
```

You can check your collate settings in psql with `SHOW lc_collate;`.

PostgreSQL uses OS collation support, so it's possible for results to vary slightly from host OS to host OS. Some versions of Mac OS X or a BSD-family operating system have problems with locale definitions.